# Generated constructor on POD vs non-POD cases

Tags: c++, constructor, compilation

I know that if no constructor is declared for a class, the compiler will generate one.
However, after compiling the following (g++ or clang++) and doing `nm -C` with this code - that have a non-POD data member - I do see the generated Ctor:

```
class X
{
public:
    void SetName(std::string name) {m_name = name;}
private:
    std::string m_name;
};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    x1.SetName("jude");

    return 0;
}
```

But with this code - with a POD data member - I don't:

```
class X
{
public:
    void SetNum(int num) {m_x = num;}
private:
    int m_x;
};

int main()
{
    X x1;
    x1.SetNum(8);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought that I would see a generated constructor in both cases. Does this behavior complies with the standard? Or is it something else that's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of

```
class X
{
public:
    void SetName(std::string name) {m_name = name;}
private:
    std::string m_name;
};
```

A constructor must be generated as `m_name` needs to be default constructed.

In the case of

```
class X
{
public:
    void SetNum(int num) {m_x = num;}
private:
    int m_x;
};
```

default constructing `m_x` is the same as doing nothing as the variable is left uninitialized.  Since not generating and calling the constructor does the same thing the constructor would do the compiler can optimize it away under the ["as-if" rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution).

Comment: Is there a compilation\linking flag I can use to disable this optimization?

Comment: @HeyJude I'm not sure.  Turning off optimizations may help but that really isn't a solution.  Do you really need the constructor?  It is a non-op.

Comment: @HeyJude You can compile the codes w/o main() just generating .o files and check those.

Comment: Well, I just thought it would be nice to know about this flag, if exists. I'll handle without it, surely. Thanks.

Comment: @Walter, Checked that. From what I know, I need to use the class, or else no member function shall be generated. Here, I use it within `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `nm -C` is *not* bound by the as-if rule. Remember, `inline` is just a hint to the compiler, and it may use any other hint it sees fit as well - including the complexity of a function. Obviously these two constructors vary in complexity. In fact, in the POD case the generated ctor literally is trivial, and it is entirely reasonable for a compiler to inline that.